# Yii2 REST giving a 405 on POST, PUT, etc

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to build a REST API in a Yii2 advanced application for managing simple queries to my database.
Following some tutorials, finally build step by step the example in the Guide, in Quick Start, and get my model working for GET and HEAD methods.

Created my API service inside a module, properly set, with minimal settings, request JSON parser on backend/main.php, registered the module in common/main.php and created the rule in urlManager there too (below the minimal usual rules, enablePrettyUrl, controller/action, ...):

```
['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['precapi']]
```

But whenever I tried some other methods, via CURL or Postman REST Client, it always gives me a **405** error:

> Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request
>   methods: GET, HEAD.

I think I have tried so many different configurations and paths trying to solve it, but without any result.
Only thing is `'enableStrictParsing' => false'` in urlManager, because it gives me a 404 error on some URLs, and POST does not work with this too, although the application is working as usual.

Any help will be appreciated.
Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without more information on what your precapi controller is based I'm going to assume it's derived from `\yii\rest\ActiveController`?

If so, you might wat to override the `verbs()`-function in your controller:
The default implementation is this:

```
protected function verbs()
{
    return [
        'index' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
        'view' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
        'create' => ['POST'],
        'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH'],
        'delete' => ['DELETE'],
    ];
}
```

I think, given your comments that there is indeed a small problem with the UrlManager configuration, so I went out reading things back and saw you added the controller to a module.
[The manual has this to say](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html#$controller-detail):

> The controller ID (e.g. user, post-comment) that the rules in this composite rule are dealing with. **It should be prefixed with the module ID if the controller is within a module (e.g. admin/user).**

Might that be the issue?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is derived form ActiveController. But I believe it's supposed to work by default without further methods, as written on documentation. namespace app\modules\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class DefaultController extends ActiveController AND there just instantiate the model from the table. Will try and let you know.

Comment: Same results with that implementation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The idea is that you modify the implementation and add 'POST' to it. I just added the default one as an example

Comment: No luck. With behaviours merging array and verbfilter or directly with verbs method. Same results. I will try with yii\rest\controller instead of ActiveController.

Comment: It is the same if I use Controller and writing basic functions Index, View, etc... Index does work, but View doesn't, giving me a 404. Same as using ActiveController. So I'm thinking about urlManager, defined in common/main.php. Anyway, any example or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean http://admin.primeapps.local:8080/precapi/default/view/1 or http://admin.primeapps.local:8080/precapi/create

Comment: if your module is `precapi` and the REST controller is `DefaultController` then the `UrlRule` should be configured as `"controller" => "precapi/default"`

Comment: Edited. Do you mean http://admin.primeapps.local:8080/precapi/default/create ? Yes, it works! Module name (inside backend) is Precapi. Controller is DefaultController. The strange thing here is it works with GET method, but not view, and HEAD. No other methods are possible, with rest\ActiveController or with rest\Controller. Now cannot access view, but I should investigate in this direction. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes. It's working, but urlManager is not working as expected. ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['precapi/default']], but I should point to precapi/default to create (POST). Although it works. And cannot see http://admin.primeapps.local:8080/precapi/default/view/4. It gives me a 404. But POST works! Have to investigate. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Since that seems to have solved your original question, please don't forget to accept the answer so that the question is marked resolved.

Comment: Only thing to note is that everything works with 'controller' => ['precapi/default']], URL routing through http://admin.primeapps.local:8080/precapi/defaults and don't forget plurals. It's on by default, and I'm not using user/users, so default is defaults! PUT http://admin.primeapps.local:8080/precapi/defaults/4 updates id=4. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14):

I think is pluralize issue, try this

```
['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'precapi', 'pluralize'=>false],
```

Answer (score 1):

I am asking on this issue, cause I had it and killed all day long to find the solution. I was very stupid. 
It is not a problem of YII2 framework, but it's a curl problem.
Not the issue with some controllers, actions or behaviors, but with right spelling curl command.

Here is wrong command - delete or put not working and raised 405 error:

curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XDELETE "http://test.test.in/test" -d '{"myid": "2"}'

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Date: Sun, 26 Jun 2016 07:47:51 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.22
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

And here is correct and right way curl's command:
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XDELETE "http://test.test.in/test/2"

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Date: Sun, 26 Jun 2016 07:49:19 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.22

That's all, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add possible problem and solution I encountered today. Its having extra `/`in URL something like `http://localhost:8080/index.php/module/controller_id/?access-token=_token_here`

Note how subtle `/` in URL is after the controller_id

That was my issue and I resolved by removing extra `/`